# Postgres Dump To TXT File

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Is there a way to convert a Postgres dump file to a text file?

I'm experiencing issues getting the dump to the proper file location of I would just restore from the dump file and then export to text.

Really I just need to import it into a SQLite database.

I think it's a binary dump. Here's what latest dump looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

This is a dump file produced by `pg_dump -Fc`. The dump may or may not contain the data depending on the options it was made with.

To create a text file containing SQL commands from it, use [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html).

The basic syntax is `pg_restore -f output.sql file.dump`, that is, you don't specify a target database (notice the missing`-d` option).  `-f-` may be used instead of `-f output.sql` to send the SQL script to the standard output.

Comment: You have to specify the original dump file using the `-f` flag otherwise `pg_restore` will complain: `pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified`.

Comment: @s.k: on newer versions, yes. I've edited the answer to conform to both pre-v12 and post-v12 versions of pg_restore.